# How to find out, that output of my program will be redirected to file?

Tags: c, unix, pipe, ls

I'm trying to recode `ls` program (man ls). If ls has no arguments and it's output is redirected trough pipe like `ls > file` than it'll use `-1` flag.
Which function i must use, to find that output is redirected?

Comment: This? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227065/303077

Comment: "redirected through pipe" is completely incorrect.  There is absolutely no pipe involved with `ls > file`.  Try writing some code that does `fseek(stdout, ..)` and run it with stdout redirected to a file.